# How can I drop all temp tables before running the same query?

Tags: sql

I read that I can prevent the 'same object exists' error with temp tables in SQL by dropping the table before running the query. However, I have several temp tables and I would like to save time from dropping each explicitly in the code. Is there something that clears up all temp tables before running the query again? Something like DROP TABLE * ? Please note I only want to drop the temp tables, not permanent ones.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: In Postgres you could use `discard temporary`

Comment: I leave 'temp' tables permanent and just delete/insert records.

Comment: I believe I use T-SQL, any luck with that?